# Calculating time for any sum to double, at a given rate of interest compounded annually

Tags: c++, while-loop, int, double

I was trying to write a program that calculates the time it takes for any sum of money to double at a given rate of interest compounded annually.

When I run this program, I have found that

- the loop is not exiting
- the counter is incremented endlessly
- with the sum stuck at 100

What am I doing wrong?

```
int main(){
    cout << "Please enter the interest rate in % per annum:";
    int counter = 0;
    int sum=100;
    int interest = 0;
    cin >> interest;
    while(sum<200){
        counter++;
        sum += sum*(interest / 100);
        }
    cout << "\n It would take about " << counter << " years to double";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interest` is an `int` so this line

```
interest / 100
```

is doing integer division, and will always be `0`. The quick fix would be to change the literal so you are doing floating point math

```
sum += sum*(interest / 100.0);
```

Comment: Unless you get a title loan with 120% interest.

Comment: I suppose if you're borrowing money from loan sharks or the mafia, then the code might work closer to correct :D